# How to filter users in microsoft graph list?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
endpoint from the Microsoft Graph API to get the users from the organisation. it is giving me a list of all the users but I want just users, those are created after 01-01-2023.

I have tried using above endpoint with **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=create/dateTime ge '2023-01-01T00:00'** but it is giving me below error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Property 'dateTime' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-17T08:19:15",
            "request-id": "3129e8a3-0f00-4e14-99fc-2741f50d12d1",
            "client-request-id": "28ecaa31-31dd-3c00-7d7c-474173eb1512"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to filter in the above endpoint with time. If you could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property name is `createdDateTime`. Do not use quotes around date and time in this case.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

To filter between two dates:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z and createdDateTime le 2023-01-07T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: and what would be the URL if I want records between 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z and 2023-01-07T00:00:00Z?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya `$filter=createdDateTime ge 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z and createdDateTime le 2023-01-07T00:00:00Z`. I've updated the answer